# Cannot set some properties of a Label within a different thread (Task.Run) in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, task

I'm sure it doesn't have anything to do with Xamarin, just tesing my understanding of tasks in general I think.  I have a task that creates a label among other things and it is in a task so I can keep the activityindicator spinning while it is running.  It just stops with no error and I narrowed it down to setting certain propertied.  for example:

```
        private void Wtf()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
       {
           var oLbl = new Label() {  Text = "Order" };  // This works
           var oLbl2 = new Label() { FontSize = 10, Text = "Order" }; // This fails with no error
       });
    }
```

Both 'Text' and 'FontSize' are properties of Label, but must be different somehow...?

Comment: if you are just creating a local variable that immediately goes out of scope, how do you know that it is failing?  Have you tried catching the exception?

Comment: what is the error reported?

Comment: Catching the error gives "The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))" which is pretty self explanatory, but I don't understand how it could be a different thread than the Text property.